# Getting the Sum For Each Date

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am writing a program in C# that read and writes to SQLite (System.Data.Sqlite)
I have a table that looks like this

```
UserID  ProdID  Value1  Value2  TIME
------------------------------------------------
1        1      10      1      2011-06-01 10:20:30.333
1        2      20      3      2011-06-01 10:20:30.444
2        1      100     11     2011-06-01 10:20:30.333
2        2      22      32     2011-06-01 10:20:30.444
1        1      20      2      2011-06-01 10:30:30.333
1        2      30      4      2011-06-01 10:30:30.444
2        1      22      22     2011-06-01 10:30:30.333
2        2      33      44     2011-06-01 10:30:30.444
1        1      10      1      2011-06-02 10:20:30.333
1        2      20      3      2011-06-02 10:20:30.444
2        1      11      11     2011-06-02 10:20:30.333
2        2      22      32     2011-06-02 10:20:30.444
1        1      20      2      2011-06-02 10:30:30.333
1        2      30      4      2011-06-02 10:30:30.444
2        1      22      22     2011-06-02 10:30:30.333
2        2      33      44     2011-06-02 10:30:30.444
```

I need to get Three things from this for each user.

1) The Last Entry of the day from each product for Value1 and 2 and totaled so its one two values that are the sum of all the products.
ie for user 1 on 2011-06-01 it would be Value1=50 and Value2=6.

curently i use:

```
SELECT * FROM TickData AS a,;
(SELECT USERID, DATE(TIME) AS JUSTDATE, MAX(TIME) AS MTIME;
FROM TickData;
GROUP BY 1,2;
) AS b;
WHERE a.USERID = b.USERID;
AND a.TIME = b.MTIME;
AND STRFTIME('%Y-%m',a.TIME) = STRFTIME('%Y-%m','NOW');
AND a.USERID = 1;
```

this returns:

```
UserID  ProdID  Value1  Value2  TIME
------------------------------------------------
1        1      20      2      2011-06-01 10:30:30.333
1        2      30      4      2011-06-01 10:30:30.444
```

For 2011-06-01.
Then i loop through the data and add the values when the dates are the same.
Giving me Value1=50 and Value2=6.

2) The Highest Entry for each day of Value1 totaled for all products.
ie for user 2 on 2011-06-01 it would be Value1=133.

```
UserID  ProdID  Value1  Value2  TIME
------------------------------------------------
2        1      100     11     2011-06-01 10:20:30.333
2        2      33      44     2011-06-01 10:30:30.444
```

3) The Lowest Entry for each day of Value1 totaled for all products.
ie for user 2 on 2011-06-01 it would be Value1=44.

```
UserID  ProdID  Value1  Value2  TIME
------------------------------------------------
2        2      22      32     2011-06-01 10:20:30.444
2        1      22      22     2011-06-01 10:30:30.333
```

I havent had any luck with 2 or 3 yet.

Does anyone have any sugestions

Comment: make it more clear ...Do you mean add all Vlaue1 and Value2 of each user and showed it with most recent time????

Comment: For 3. why is it Value1=44 for user 1, shouldn't it be 10 + 20 = 30?

Comment: Sorry was a typo it was ment to be user 2 but yes for user one it would be 30

Comment: @Syeda no the code i have already does that. I need the Value1 and 2 for the end of each day for each product then add all the products up so you get one set of value1 and 2 that is the total of all products at the end of a day for each day for a user. i update the example a little to try to clear it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok worked it out my self over the weekend

1)

```
SELECT sum(value1), sum(value2) FROM TickData AS a,
(SELECT USERID, PRODID, DATE(TIME) AS JUSTDATE, MAX(TIME) AS MTIME
FROM TickData
GROUP BY 1,2,3
) AS b
WHERE a.USERID = b.USERID
AND a.TIME = b.MTIME
AND STRFTIME('%Y-%m',a.TIME) = STRFTIME('%Y-%m','NOW')
AND a.USERID = 1
GROUP BY JUSTDATE
```

2)

```
SELECT sum(Mval) FROM TickData AS a,
(SELECT USERID, PRODID, DATE(TIME) AS JUSTDATE,ID, MAX(value1) AS Mval
FROM TickData
GROUP BY 1,2,3
) AS b
WHERE a.USERID = b.USERID
AND a.ID = b.ID
AND STRFTIME('%Y-%m',a.TIME) = STRFTIME('%Y-%m','NOW')
AND a.USERID = 2
GROUP BY JUSTDATE
```

3)

```
SELECT sum(Mval) FROM TickData AS a,
(SELECT USERID, PRODID, DATE(TIME) AS JUSTDATE,ID, MIN(value1) AS Mval
FROM TickData
GROUP BY 1,2,3
) AS b
WHERE a.USERID = b.USERID
AND a.ID = b.ID
AND STRFTIME('%Y-%m',a.TIME) = STRFTIME('%Y-%m','NOW')
AND a.USERID = 2
GROUP BY JUSTDATE
```

Edit:
2 and 3 can be done with one query:

```
SELECT sum(Mval), sum(Mval2) FROM TickData AS a,
(SELECT USERID, PRODID, DATE(TIME) AS JUSTDATE,ID, MAX(PL) AS Mval,MIN(PL) AS Mval2
FROM TickData
GROUP BY 1,2,3
) AS b
WHERE a.USERID = b.USERID
AND a.TIME = b.MTIME
AND STRFTIME('%Y-%m',a.TIME) = STRFTIME('%Y-%m','NOW')
AND a.USERID = 2
GROUP BY JUSTDATE
```